# Python 3.X - only take number from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on a problem that I am trying to solve. I am only suppose to take int (1-4) from user's input and not take any string/float/etc. I have figured out what to do if a user chooses any integer other than 1-4. However, I am stuck on the part where a user chooses anything other than an integer (i.e string, float, etc).
this is what I have done so far:

```
    def menu():
       my code
    menu()

    # keeps on looping till user have selected a proper selection (1-4)
   selection = int(input("> "))
     if selection == 1: 
       my code
     elif selection == 2: 
       my code
     elif selection == 3: 
       my code
     elif selection == 4: 
       my code
     else:
      print("I'm sorry, that's not a valid selection. Please enter a 
      selection from 1-4. ")
      menu()
```

Any help would be appriciated. I've been trying to find a solution for hours but got stuck on the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you don't appear to be doing any integer operations on the value coming from `input` - I would personally just leave it as a string.

```
selection = input("> ")
if selection == "1":
    pass
elif selection == "2":
    pass
#...
else:
    print("I'm sorry...")
```

By doing this you don't have to deal with that edge case at all.

---

If you must (for some reason) cast this to an `int` (like, you're using the value later) then you could consider using exception handling.

```
try:
    selection = int(input("> "))
except ValueError:
    selection = "INVALID VALUE"
```

and the continue you on, as your current else statement will catch this and correctly handle it.

Comment: awesome, it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this If you make sure that your code allows the user to input only numbers in python:

```
def numInput():
    try:
        number = int(input("Tell me a number"))
    except:
        print "You must enter a number"
        numInput()

    return number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an infinite loop to keep asking the user for an integer within the desired range until the user enters one:

```
while True:
    try:
        selection = int(input("> "))
        if 1 <= selection <= 4:
            break
        raise RuntimeError()
    except ValueError, RuntimeError:
        print("Please enter a valid integer between 1 and 4.")
```